# How to get parent div of clicked dynamically bound anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get parent div of clicked dynamically bound anchor tag?
I am binding multiple images with multiple delete anchor tags on file upload button click. like below

```
$('#images').on('change', function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files;
      $.each(files, function(i, file) {
            fileCollection.push(file);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function(e) {

                var templated = '<div id="imgPreView' + i + '" class="col-md-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                  '<img class="img-responsive" id="targetImg' + i + '" src="' + e.target.result + '"/> ' +
                  '<div class="caption">' +
                  '<a href="#" onclick="ClearPreview(' + i + ')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>' +
                  '<span id="description"></span>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '</div>';

                $('#images-to-upload').append(templated);
```

but when I want to delete image in ClearPreview() function its deleting correct indexed div and image but when I supposed to upload some other images and trying to delete some indexed img but its deleting some other img...

```
function ClearPreview(i) {
  $('#images' + i).val('');
  $('#imgPreView' + i).remove();
}
```

so how to delete current anchor tag's clicked image and div?

Comment: $(this).parent(); statement to your ClearPreview() function will give you parent div for clicked element having class "caption" dynamically

Comment: You will need to update the indexes when you delete. That wrong index might be causing issues

Comment: `$(this).parent().remove();` will remove the parent element of your current selection.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent();` statement to your **ClearPreview()** function will give you parent div for clicked element having class "caption" dynamically

Comment: what could be syntax plz?

Comment: as my opinion you just need to give classname to anchor tag suppose and just call click event by class name so it will work for all anchor of that class and just add above code

$(this).parent().Id will give you id of specific div & then you can delete or empty any element by ID